# iTunes Connect data not updating since 2 days?

Tags: app-store-connect

UPDATE: "Please note that data for Feb 3rd and Feb 4th is currently incomplete.  We are working to correct the issue and apologize for the inconvenience."
Sometimes pops up now. In the notification, only the 3rd was mentioned before, but now apprently they updated the message.

former question:

The statistics in iTunes Connect seem to be stuck on the 2nd of February. Am I the only one to experience this? Haven't found any other recent posts about this yet.

I already tried another browser, this is what I see:

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've have the same problem on the webpage but on the iPhone app the service works fine.

Comment: Didn't try this, cheers mate. Is yours stuck on 02/02 as well?

Comment: Yep on 02/02 too.